# Updating Entity Designer

Tags: entity-framework

How can I update the Entity Designer of Entity Framework to the latest version? Since 4.1, Microsoft started using NuGet, which means the Entity Designer won't be updated when we update Entity Framework through NuGet:

"The Entity Designer will continue to be installed with Visual Studio and will work with the latest version of EF." --- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/10/18/how-we-talk-about-ef-and-its-future-versions.aspx

I am asking this question because I can't find the option "Convert To Enum" described in this article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/walkthrough-enums-june-ctp.aspx

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Convert To Enum is not available because it depends on new version of EF which doesn't exists yet - it was only previewed in June 2011 CTP. It will be part of Visual Studio 11 and .NET Framework 4.5.

Comment: @Adam: Designer itself also wasn't released as separate update for VS 2010 but it is part of VS 11 Beta.

Comment: you can add the enum feature and others inprovements listed here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/10/11/entity-designer-improvements-preview.aspx just install these files: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26660 so change the target framework in project properties to "Framework June 2011 CTP"